# Could I use Tukey's HSD test as a post-hoc test for a within-groups ANOVA test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, tukey-hsd-test, multiple-comparisons

I understand Tukey's HSD is the most common post-hoc test for between-groups ANOVA. It appears some do not recommend or select it as a post-hoc test for within-groups ANOVA.  Instead, they prefer Bonferroni test or Sidak test. But, both of those seem to just multiply whatever *p*-value you would get from a paired t-test by the number of hypotheses you are testing. This approach seems less than robust. Instead, if I could I would rather use Tukey's HSD test in this situation [within-groups ANOVA]. Could I do that? Or are there specific reasons not to.

Comment: What do you mean by “less than robust”? Bonferroni is always possible and guaranteed to provide strong control of the family-wise error rate. The problem is that it is often unnecessarily conservative/looses power.

Comment: Not sure this addresses your question fully but you might find the following resource helpful: http://www.uvm.edu/~dhowell/StatPages/More_Stuff/RepMeasMultComp/RepMeasMultComp.html

Comment: Gael, it is an interesting reference.  But, it does not address the question.

Comment: AFAIK, only Bonferroni, Sidak and possibly Games-Howell post-hoc devices are safe to use with repeated-measures. Other traditional post-hoc tests won't do because they are ment for independent error terms. The test of spericity p-value should be 0.5 (not 0.05) or higher, for them, and this is seldom.

Comment: ttnphns, thanks for the insightful comment.  Actually, this seems like a good answer.  Do you want to move it to the Answer section so we could vote on it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do Tukey on a within subjects variable.  You'll find the info in Keppel's book on ANOVA.  SPSS doesn't include tukey for within subjects variables, but you can easily compute it by hand.

Comment: Welcome to [stats.se].
Thank you for your answer.
Can you please [edit] you answer to expand it, in order to include the main points of the book you cite? It will be more helpful for people searching in this site.
By the way, take the opportunity to take the [Tour], if you haven't done it already. See also some tips on 
[answer], on 
[formatting help](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)
and on writing down equations using 
[LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).